# Java Extending StreamPrintService -- how do I implement a 'Print to Postscript File' type of 'printer'?

Tags: java, printing

I am having a hard time trying to something simple in Java, but I have been beating my head against a wall for the better part of a day.

I am implementing a program that has a print feature.  What I want to print is HTML text in a JEditorPane and I know I can use the print() method to print it to a *printer*, but I want to also print it to a file (PostScript or PDF, I don't really care which).  I know that there exists somewhere in the depths of the JRE is code to convert the rendered contents of the JEditorPane to PostScript, since the printers I am dealing with are PostScript printers and that that is the standard output format for UNIX/Linux printers.  Is there a way to leverage that to print to a *file*, without having to completely re-invent the wheel? I have been running web searches and randomly hacking code for the past couple of days with absolutely no meaningful progress.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I just want to add the option to 'Print to File'.  That functionalliy *appears* to be completely missing in Java.  I don't know any better was of describing the problem.  In just about *every* other application toolkit there is a 'Print to File' option.  How do I add it?  The API suggests a *possible* way, but it is very dragonian (more so than it really ought to be).  Or is it that Java is just an excessively draconian programming system?

Comment: I'd bet the conversion to PostScript is actually handled by the operating system's printer driver, not by Java itself.  I'm not familiar with printing in Java, but you might have more success trying to invoke the OS-native printing system with JNI/JNA/BridJ.

Comment: [This page in the Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtext.html) shows a "standard print dialog" including a print-to-file checkbox.  I'm not sure why you don't see the same.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this is just not easily doable with Java.  Instead, I found a package that implements 'exporting' the contents of the GUI (a JTextPane) to a PDF file, so I just added an additional toolbar button & menu item to 'Export to PDF'.